# Relationship between two intermediate entities in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have five entities :
**ProductA**, **ProductB**, **User**, **UserProductA** and **UserProductB**. The two last ones are "intermediate" entites which contain the attributes of relationships between **ProductA**, **ProductB** and **User**.

I would like to make a ManyToOne relationship between **UserProductA** and **UserProductB** but it doesn't work. When I try to update the database, I get this error : **Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity**.

UserProductA (without the relationship) :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gam\UserBundle\Entity\UserProductARepository")
 */
class UserProductA
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gam\FicheBundle\Entity\ProductA")
   */
  private $producta;

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gam\UserBundle\Entity\User")
   */
  private $user;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
   */
  private $attribute;

  etc...
}
```

UserProductB (without the relationship) :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gam\UserBundle\Entity\UserProductBRepository")
 */
class UserProductB
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gam\FicheBundle\Entity\ProductB")
   */
  private $productb;

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gam\UserBundle\Entity\User")
   */
  private $user;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
   */
  private $attribute;

  etc...
}
```

How can I make it work ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using multiple (aka composite) primary keys? If you're not intending to, why do you have `@ORM\Id` listed multiple times in your entities? [Read more here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#composite-keys). Is there perhaps an `@ORM\GeneratedValue` in either of the entities?

Comment: So if I've well understood, your sample code is working well, but when you had your UserProductA > UserProductB ManyToOne relationship you got this error ?